# Python - extracting very specific words / strings from each row of pd.Series

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a pd.Series like below:

### Text

```
0    some text here...B.Com EMA...

1    some more text here...B.Sc

2    Few more here....M.Com

3    Last but not least.....M.Sc
```

What I am looking for a suitable regex (or pd.Series.str.findall / match) so that I can pick up B.Sc, M.Com and M.Sc and put them in a new pd.Series.

Comment: hi any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.contains`to create a boolean filter, and then apply this to your series:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['abcM.Sc', 'abcB.Sc', 'ghiM.Com', 'jklM.Sc', 'jklB.Sc', 
'jklB.Com', 'jklM.Com'])

filter = s.str.contains('B.Sc')

s[filter]
```

returns

```
1    'abcB.Sc'
4    'jklB.Sc'
dtype: object
```

If instead you want a series which shows just the qualification for each row, you could use `Series.apply()` with a function:

```
def qual(text): 
    if 'M.Sc' in text: 
        qualification =  'M.Sc' 
    elif 'B.Sc' in text:
        qualification =  'B.Sc'
    elif 'B.Com' in text:
        qualification =  'B.Com'
    elif 'M.Com' in text:
        qualification =  'M.Com'
    else:
        qualification = ''

    return qualification

qualifications = s.apply(lambda x: qual(x))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use like this as well: s.str.contains('B.Sc|MSc.')?

Comment: The above answer is not what I am looking for. What I want is 'extraction' of 'B.Sc' or 'M.Sc.' words from the pd.Series. The above answer only confirms whether the specified words are there in the rows or not.

Comment: @pythondumb so you want to return a series which just gives the qualification, rather than the other bits?